# Org-mode define face for pandoc citation syntax

Tags: faces, pandoc

I would like to set a new face in org-mode for pandoc citation syntax which looks like this:

```
[@bibtexkey{555-563}]
```

Custom face:

```
(defface pandoc-citation-face
  '((t :foreground "yellow"))
  "Face for pandoc citation syntax")
```

None of the attempts below worked:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
      '(("\[@.+?\]" . pandoc-citation-face)))
```

```
(defun org-add-my-extra-markup ()
  (add-to-list 'org-font-lock-extra-keywords
               `(("\[@.+?\]" . pandoc-citation-face))))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook #'org-add-my-extra-markup)
```

```
(defun org-add-my-extra-markup ()
  (add-to-list 'org-font-lock-extra-keywords
               `(,(rx (group "[@")
                      (group (+? anything))
                      (group "]"))
                 (2 '(face pandoc-citation)))))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook #'org-add-my-extra-markup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
(defface pandoc-citation-face
  '((t :foreground "yellow"))
  "Face for pandoc citation syntax")

(font-lock-add-keywords
 nil
 '(("\\[@.+?\\]" 0 'pandoc-citation-face)))
```